# backbone collection keeping sort order on model mutation

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, coffeescript

If I have a collection with a comparator. ( in coffeescript )

```
class Words extends Backbone.collection
    comparator: (word)->
        word.get('score')
```

how do I keep the collection sorted if I am changing
the score of the underlying items. The idea is to
attach this to a list view where items with the
lowest score are always at the top.

I've been manually calling sort on the collection
every time I mutate an instance but this doesn't seem
too efficient given that the whole list is sorted
with one item.

I might perhaps try removing the mutated item and
then add it again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 for using CoffeeScript — the _future_ !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the rendering code is highly inefficient for one simple reason: **DOM manipulation is expensive.** Whenever possible, you should manipulate the DOM once rather than several times. All other optimization in JavaScript/CoffeeScript is secondary.

Here's the salient code (from the gist linked to from the second comment on ambertch's response):

```
refresh: ->
    @list.listview("refresh")

appendWord: (word)->
    wv = new WordView({model: word}).render().el
    @list.append( wv )
    @refresh()

render: ->
    @list.html("")
    @model.each (word) => @appendWord(word)
    @refresh()
```

So, on `render`, first the list's HTML is cleared; then *for each word* the list's HTML is cleared *and* the control is refreshed!

I'm not familiar with jQuery Mobile, so I'm not sure whether the main penalty is incurred on `append` (as it is in jQuery) or on `listview('refresh')`, but it's easy to rewrite the loop to avoid both, and remove some function defining/calling overhead as well:

```
render: ->
  html = []
  @model.each (word) ->
    html.push(new WordView(model: word).render().el)
  @list.empty().append(html)
```

Now you've got just one `html` setter and one `refresh` call, rather than one `html` setter, *n* `append` calls, and *n+1* `refresh` calls!

Comment: It doesn't quite work. html = '' is a string whereas html += is adding DOM objects. Trying to fix it....

Comment: turns out the really slow bit is the @refresh call where jquery mobile ui re-renders the chrome for the UI. I had a really bad bit of code you spotted where I called refresh multi times. Removing that was a big help.

Comment: Good call about `.el`; I've corrected the code by putting a jQuery wrapper around each new element and using `.html`. However, this adds a bit of overhead as well. I believe a more efficient approach would be to do `html += '<li>' + new WordView(model: word).render().el.innerHTML + '</li>'`.

Answer (score 0):

How about binding all of a Words' initial models to sort on a change event, and then bind the same on an add event to the collection?

```
_(self).models.each(model) { model.bind('change', self.sort) } // bind on the model add as well
```

Backbone.Collection.sort triggers a refresh, so then just:

```
this.bind('refresh', this.refresh)
```

As to your concern about efficiency, what do you mean by "the whole list is sorted with one item?"   Unless you have THOUSANDS of items (and even then, run some benchmarks in various browsers, I bet it would still be pretty damn fast), it shouldn't make much difference with modern browsers/computers

If you were really concerned about it, I guess you can do some of the optimization techniques for keeping larger sets sorted. For example, drop them in score buckets (0-100, 100-500, 500-1000, etc.), then drop the score in the bucket and only sort within the bucket (the actual sort algorithm is per browser implementation, Backbone - or Underscore rather, just calls it). You can google for algorithms like this. But it's a lot of work for little gain vs. the increase in code complexity.

Again, though, you'd need a lot of profiling and benchmarking to determine if this is actually worth it.

Comment: turns out that it is not the sorting that is a performance killer but the re-rendering of the list on a mobile platform. I only have about 40 items and my list re-render is taking 3 seconds. I'm using JQuery mobile UI on HTC desire.

Comment: The gist for the rendering code is at https://gist.github.com/899825 perhapps I'm doing something stupid in the rendering code??